# BeautifulSoup FindAll with OR and Empty Class

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, findall

I am trying to extract the following:

```
<td class="indent">Interest Income on Fed. Funds</td>
<td class="">-</td>
```

with this

```
interest=a.findAll("td",{'class':[''|'indent']},limit=6)
```

However, it returns

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'str'

How could I find empty class OR class_='indent'?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
interest = a.findAll("td", {'class': [None, 'indent']}, limit=6)
```

1. Pass multiple classes as a list (with `,` separator not with `|`)
2. Select empty classes with `None`

Comment: I can see that we've posted the same solution, but you posted it a few seconds before me. So do I have to delete my answer or keep it? I don't know the rules regarding this.

Comment: I don't think such rule exists, it's up to you :)

Answer (score 2):

Another option as well for bs4:

```
def empty_or_indent(css_class):
    return css_class is None or css_class is 'indent'   

a.find_all('td', class_=empty_or_indent, limit=6)
```